# How to create VPC Link for WebSocket for API Gateway private integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I want to expose a websocket service running in a VPC through API Gateway. I have created an NLB  to the service in private subnet.

I'm following [this API Gateway integration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-integration-requests.html) which asks me to [setup API Gateway private integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html) (one of the integration types). There onwards the examples are all for HTTP/REST.

In the VPC link creation page I see two options:
[image]

First option allows me select an NLB but it is for REST. The second option only has the option to select a VPC, subnet and security group.

How do I setup VPC Link for websocket API?

Comment: Any solution for above problem? I am also facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to create a VPC Link for a WebSocket API from the Integration Request window.

First select you WebSocket API and then click on $connect in the Routes tab. There you will find the "Integration Request" block where you can configure a VPC Link integration type. It seems like you can only integrate with REST APIs VPC Links, which seems a bit confusing to me either.

[image]